# once custom system master page is assigned then unable to store the image library data or metadata

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I am unable to save the picture library items, Alternate column. (This is Custom picture library)
But I can if there is System Master page is **Seattle**.
So how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Post the custom master page code in here. Also what the screen grab of master page setting.